# Display in Row and Column images using map function

Tags: reactjs

/* I am trying to display in Row and Column images store in an array object called itemToSell using map function but unfortunately my images appear only in Column can someone help me Why The Row doesn't work on this code??
funny is that this is the way i used to display in Row and Column array Object using map function thats create different Card Component and it used to work but this time i don't know why the Row doesn't affect the code!
*/

```
const itemToSell=[
    {
        id : 1,
        img:"./Images/image1.jpg",
        Description:"Avocado",
        Price: "R30",
    },

    {
        id : 2,
        img:"./Images/image2.webp",
        Description:"Orange",
        Price: "R30",
    },

    {
        id : 3,
        img:"./Images/image3.jpeg",
        Description:"Apple",
        Price: "R30",
    },

    {
        id : 4,
        img:"./Images/image4.jpeg",
        Description:"Banana",
        Price: "R30",
    },

    {
        id : 5,
        img:"./Images/image5.jpeg",
        Description:"Mango",
        Price: "R30",
    },

    {
        id : 6,
        img:"./Images/image6.jpeg",
        Description:"Kiwi",
        Price: "R30",
    },

    {
        id : 7,
        img:"./Images/image7.jpeg",
        Description:"Waterlemon",
        Price: "R30",
    },
    {
        id : 8,
        img:"./Images/image8.jpeg",
        Description:"Apricot",
        Price: "R30",
    },

    {
        id : 9,
        img:"./Images/image9.jpeg",
        Description:"Grapes",
        Price: "R30",
    },
    
    {
        id : 10,
        img:"./Images/image10.jpeg",
        Description:"Cherry",
        Price: "R30",
    },
]

export default itemToSell
```

```
import React from 'react';
import itemToSell from './itemToSell';
import {Card,Button,Row,Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';

function DisplayProduct() {
  const element = itemToSell.map((product,index) =>
    <div key={index}> {/*refer you key in within a div*/}
      <Col>
        {product.id} {/*Use this line of code if you wanna display your key value*/}
        <Card style={{ width: '15rem' }}>
        <Card.Img variant="top" src={product.img} />
        <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>{product.Description}</Card.Title>
        <Button variant="primary">Add {product.Price}</Button>
        </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    </div>
 
  )
    return (
        <div>
          <Container>
            <Row>
              {element}
            </Row>  
          </Container>               
        </div>
    )
}
export default DisplayProduct
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return (
        <div>
          <Container>
            <Row xs={1} md={2}>
              {element}
            </Row>  
          </Container>               
        </div>
    )
```

/* inside the `<Row>` you need to precise the html attribute that will define the screen display; xs,md,lg,etc*/